# Unable to use artisan command in newly created Laravel Jetsteam 3.x project

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I'm beginning to learn Laravel, so my experience and understanding of the Laravel ecosystem is low, at this time of writing.

I am following the [Laravel Jetstream 3.x Installation](https://jetstream.laravel.com/3.x/installation.html) docs, which states:

> You may use Composer to install Jetstream into your new Laravel project:
>
> `composer require laravel/jetstream`
>
> After installing the Jetstream package, you may execute the `jetstream:install` Artisan command.

I have a newly created project, contained in `~/projects/work/jewelry`, I created this with:

```bash
mkdir jewelry
cd jewelry
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

I try to run the Artisan command, as the docs state: `php artisan laravel:jetstream`

But I get the error message: `Could not open input file: artisan`

My thought process was that... maybe I need to install the Laravel framework first, because that's where I remember the `artisan` command residing? But in the docs there's this big old red warning box:

> New Applications Only
>
> Jetstream should only be installed into new Laravel applications. Attempting to install Jetstream into an existing Laravel application will result in unexpected behavior and issues.

So, I'm led to believe that I shouldn't install the Laravel framework prior to installing Jetstream. Yet, I'm no closer to understanding how to use the `artisan` command from inside a Jetstream project.

What am I misunderstanding?

Addendum:
I tried doing `composer create-project laravel/jetstream jewelry` as well, to see if maybe creating the project would make a difference, and while this seems closer to what I want, the `artisan` command still isn't present, I still receive the error `Could not open input file: artisan`.

Answer (score 0):

So, I *do* need to create a Laravel project beforehand.

The solution is

```bash
cd ..
rm -r jewelry
composer create-project laravel/laravel jewelry
cd jewelry
composer require laravel/jetstream
```

From then, I am able to run `php artisan jetstream:install inertia`.